# jQgrid - setting column name as call values

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is is possible to set the column header value as one of the cell values?

I can get the cell value I need using:

`var example = $('#grid').getCell(0, 'cellname');`

i.e.

```
colNames: [example, "Name2", "Name3", "Name 4", "Name 5"],
```

However, I haven't found a way I can get this as a column name, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods), you can find the method `setLabel`. I think you can use it like this:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var example = $('#GRID_ID').getCell(0, 'cellname');
    $("#GRID_ID").jqGrid("setLabel", 0, example); //'0' is the index and 'example' is the new name
}
```